# Logging Rest Assured's own headers

Tags: java, spring, filter, rest-assured

I'm trying to get access to the HTTP headers that are injected by Rest Assured.  Spring's Mock MVC gives you access to pretty much everything via the MvcResult, and you can use this result to log pretty much anything you would like about the request and response.  The only way I can see how to do this is in RestAssured is with a Filter.  However, it gives you limited access to the request (you just get the RequestSpecification).  I understand that it might be tricky to get access to headers that are added by the HttpClient, but it doesn't look like you can even get access to headers that are added by Rest Assured itself.  For example, I can't see any OAuth related headers, nor content-type or content-length.  The only headers that appear are those that were manually added using, for example, `.contentType(ContentType.XML)`

Is there any other way to get access to those headers?  I don't need to modify the request, I just want to be able to log all of it and the headers that are injected by Rest Assured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's possible to register your own `HttpClientFactory` with RestAssured:

```
RestAssured.config().httpClient(
  HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().httpClientFactory(
    new CustomHttpClientFactory())
```

So I created a new factory that returns an HTTP client into which I inject some request and response interceptors.

```
public class CustomHttpClientFactory extends HttpClientConfig.HttpClientFactory {
    @Override
    public HttpClient createHttpClient() {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.addRequestInterceptor((request, ctx) -> {
            // do what you will 
        });
        client.addResponseInterceptor((response, ctx) -> {
            // do what you will
        });
        return client;
    }
}
```

This gives you almost full access to manipulate the request and response.  One thing to remember is that if you're going to read from the response's entity, you should first wrap it in a `BufferedHttpEntity` to make it re-readable:

```
if (response.getEntity() != null && !response.getEntity().isRepeatable()) {
    response.setEntity(new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity()));
}
```

Another problem I ran into is when trying to see the OAuth related information.  When using RestAssured's OAuth functionality, it adds its own `OAuthSigner` interceptor to the HTTP client right before executing the request.  This means that it will always be the last interceptor to be called and any interceptor you may have already injected will be called before the request ever gets signed.  Because I don't really need to see the signature for now, I didn't investigate this further and I'm leaving it as an exercise for the reader.  ;)