# How to set the content type in interceptors in rest assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have set content type in interceptors but while running the API,interceptors is not getting called.

```
package com.gdn.qa.module.athens.api.interceptors;

import com.gdn.qa.automation.core.restassured.ServiceInterceptor;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class AthensIAGInterceptor implements ServiceInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean isSupport(String serviceName) {
        if (serviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("athens_iag")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    enter code here
    @Override
    public void prepare(RequestSpecification resp1) {
         resp1 = given().log().all().contentType("application/json");
    }
}
```

Please help me, if I'm missing any steps.

Comment: [Logging Rest Assured's own headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30948047/14868118) I think this link is the answer you're looking for. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try contentType(ContentType.JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Below example is set contentType(ContentType.JSON) before sending the request, also in the response you can validate that is it equal to the same by putting it after then().

```
    given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).queryParam("page","2").when().get("https://reqres.in/api/users").then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).assertThat().statusCode(200).log().all();
```